# MFC open default email client

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

Using visual studio 2010.

I have a requirement to open default email client (usually it is outlook) from the application when a button is clicked. Message subject and body is prepopulated. User then enters the email id and sends the email. I had achieved this using `mailto:`, but I have 2 problems:

1. can't format the body text(bold or want to set a color),since only plain/text is supported.
2. character limit.

Is there any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO :). Can you show us your code please?

Comment: Google "mapi win32". You should explain what you mean by _"character limit."_

Comment: @jabberwocky I read somewhere that mailto has a character restriction of 255.i assumed it is for body text.

Comment: @jabberwocky mapi is only for outlook right. What if there is some other email client installed at client place? With mailto It would just open whatever the default application. And also can you give me sample mapi code. Extended mapi I bit difficult to go through

Comment: No, it also works with other email clients. And no, I Don't have code. For mapi. Google is your friend

Comment: @jabberwocky ok thanks